# Webscraping from a dynamic website without using selenium

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, python-requests

I'm trying to scrape from a dynamic website with the obstical that I must not use selenium. In addition, the program must be able to run in google colaboratory on any computer, without anything being downloaded or the program gaining access to the operating system on the computer running it.

The website that i am trying to scrape from is:
https://www.tradingview.com/symbols/NASDAQ-AAPL/

Here, i'm trying to get the stock price.

In my own browser, I can manually locate the stock price to:

```
<div class="tv-symbol-price-quote__value js-symbol-last"> == $0
   <span>166.50</span>
</div>
```

But when I use the request module, which I would typically use to scrape, then it doesn't appear. I expect it to be because they use js to live update it.

Is there any way this is possible to do under these restrictions?

Comment: Allready looked for an api or an alternativ website that will provide these information?

Comment: this site has its own language here:  https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/primer/Next_steps.html#how-scripts-are-executed

Answer (score 0):

Using the Network monitor on my browser devtools, I noticed the data is rendered  by pushing a POST request to https://scanner.tradingview.com/america/scan.

```
import requests

post_json = {
    "symbols": {
        "tickers": ["NYSE:F", "NASDAQ:AAPL"], # It supports multiple input
        "query": {
            "types":[]
            }
        },
    "columns":["close"] # From your ask, I get that you are looking for the closing price
}

response = requests.post('https://scanner.tradingview.com/america/scan', json = post_json)

if response.status_code == 200:
    print(response.json())
else:
    print(response.status_code)
```

Hope this approach fixes it.